# Change HikariCP Logging file

Tags: java, slf4j, hikaricp

I am currently using Sl4j 1.7.25 with logback-classic-1.2.3

The logback.xml put inside the class path of the tomcat i.e WEB-INF/classes is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/foodini.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

This works fine and everything gets logged inside the foodini.log file under tomcat logs directory.

Now unfortunately, HikariCp also logs to the same file and constantly at an interval of around 30 seconds. It basically writes pool events and leaks and all. I need this to go in a separate file say hikari.log rather than inside foodini.log which is meant to be the logs of just my webapp to avoid clutter.

I tried :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/foodini.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <appender name="HIKARI" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/hikari.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari">
    <appender-ref ref="HIKARI" />
  </logger>

  <root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

It does create a new file called hikari.log but all things still get logged inside foodini.log

For any one servlet i use :

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServeletName.class);
```

to get the logger and it works fine.

EDIT: added a logger configuration to the logback file and now logs go to both the files foodini.log and hikari.log... Now i need the hikari logs from going in foodini.log file at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone interested, the configuration logback.xml i created is nearly correct, only one thing was missing and that was the additivity property on the logger element. Without that set to false, the hikari logs would go to both files instead of exclusively going to hikari.log files, heres the updated and working configuration example to get two different log file, one fore the tomcat webapp and one for hikari config,pool and error logs

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/foodini.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="HIKARI" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.home}/logs/hikari.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%logger] [%-5level] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="ALL" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="HIKARI" />
</logger>

<root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```